# Pagination c# aspx help using listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web

```
 protected void showproduct()
    {
        int pagecount = 0;
        int currentpage = 0;
        if (Request.QueryString["page"] != null)
        {
            currentpage = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["page"]);
        }

        Response.Write("</br>"+currentpage);
        MySqlConnection dbcon = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=ip; Uid=root; Password=root;");
        MySqlCommand dbcmd = new MySqlCommand();
        dbcon.Open();
        dbcmd.Connection = dbcon;
        for (int q = 0; q <= currentpage; q++)
        {
            if (currentpage >2 )
            {
                pagecount = q * 3;
            }else if(currentpage==2){
                pagecount = 3;
            }
        }
        dbcmd.CommandText = "select * from product where id >" + pagecount + " order by id asc limit 3";
        //dbcmd.CommandText = "select * from product limit "+ pagecount +",3";
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(dbcmd.CommandText, dbcon);
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(t);
        ListView1.DataSource = t;
        ListView1.DataBind();

    }
```

http://prntscr.com/d83mgh 
In page 2 I can view

http://prntscr.com/d83msj
When clicked on page 3 nothing is shown

I have like 9 data in my source

Comment: You should try to improve your question adding a good explanation on what are you trying to do and where is the issue.

Comment: Your question is VERY vague. But I think you should take a look at [DataPager Control](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-DataPager-control-with-example-in-ASPNet.aspx).

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate how you solved this issue to help somebody else who has a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the items in the db have continuous ids without holes.

Then you can calculate the first id to be shown using the index of the selected page and the number of items to be shown per page like this:

```
const int itemsPerPage = 3; // number of items per page to be shown
const int minId = 1; // id of first record in db

// page selected by user in ui
int selectedPage;
if (Request.QueryString["page"] != null) {
    // first page has index 0 to simplify the calculation
    selectedPage  = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["page"]) - 1;
}

// id of first record to be shown
int minIdToBeShown = minId + itemsPerPage * selectedPage;

// fetch records including the first record to be shown on the page
dbcmd.CommandText = "select * from product where id >=" + minIdToBeShown 
                  + " order by id asc limit " + itemsPerPage;
```